# How to properly get record records seperated by commas

Tags: reactjs

The code below display records properly via reactjs.
now I need to get and print name values each seperated by an underscore.

something like

```
{name1} {email1} {phoneno1}
{name2} {email2} {phoneno2}
```

Is this possible. Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>

   </head>
   <body>
<script src="build/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="build/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="build/browser.min.js"></script>
<script src="build/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>

<script type="text/babel">

class Application extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {

rec: {"results": 
[

{"name": "name1_email1_phoneno1", "id": "101"},
{"name": "name2_email2_phoneno2", "id": "102"},

], "page": 1}

    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>

         //
          <ul>
            {this.state.rec.results.map((obj, i) => (
              <li key={i}>
                {obj.id} - {obj.name} 

              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Application />, document.getElementById('app'));
</script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>


   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've applied a solution down below.
please follow the comments with-in the code to get the changes.

```
<script type="text/babel">

class Application extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {

rec: {"results": 
[

{"name": "name1_email1_phoneno1", "id": "101"},
{"name": "name2_email2_phoneno2", "id": "102"},

], "page": 1}

    };
  }

  // this will replace '_' with ' - '
  // output for "name_email_phonenum" --> name - email - phonenum
  function getValuesStringFromName(name){
    return name.replace(/_/, ' - ');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>

         //
          <ul>
            {this.state.rec.results.map((obj, i) => (
              <li key={i}>
                {obj.id} - {obj.name} - {this.getValuesStringFromName(obj.name).bind(this)}

              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Application />, document.getElementById('app'));
</script>
```

Comment: it throws error unexpected token pointing at `getValuesStringFromName()` function between thanks for your response

Comment: I need to remove word function and then remove the binding in the render thus I implemented the binding immediately after the state parameter and thus it work now with `{this.getValuesStringFromName(obj.name)}`. Your solution really help me so am accepting it as the best

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      rec: {
        results: [
          { name: "name1_email1_phoneno1", id: "101" },
          { name: "name2_email2_phoneno2", id: "102" }
        ],
        page: 1
      }
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <ul>
            {this.state.rec.results.map((obj, i) => (
              <li key={i}>
               { /* Change comma ',' to whatever  */ }
                {obj.id} - {obj.name.replace(/_/g, ', ')}
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: @NancyMooree You're welcome, Yes, Sultan code will work after your changes though, you'll need to add `g` flag to the `replace` function. otherwise you'll having `_` in the second value.  `name1, email1_phoneno1`